# undefined reference to `MinimalSubscriber::<attribute>' in ROS2 node

Tags: c++, ros2

i am trying to process some images with opencv, which i received from ros2.
But when i tried to create some attributes in ros2 subscriber node.

1. I created **static float slope;**.
2. Then i initialized it in **MinimalSubscriber():Node("minimal_subscriber")**.
3. In the end i want to use this attribute in the method **void topic_callback(...)**, and maybe i can change it to a new value.

I cannot define this value in my method **void topic_callback(...)**, because i want to change it in the runtime.

i do not get any error in my IDE, but when i try to build it with

```
colcon build ...
```

i get following error from my terminal:

```
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/adas_node.dir/src/adas_node.cpp.o: in function `MinimalSubscriber::MinimalSubscriber()':
adas_node.cpp:(.text._ZN17MinimalSubscriberC2Ev[_ZN17MinimalSubscriberC5Ev]+0x111): undefined reference to `MinimalSubscriber::slope'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/adas_node.dir/src/adas_node.cpp.o: in function `MinimalSubscriber::topic_callback(std::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::msg::Image_<std::allocator<void> > >) const':
adas_node.cpp:(.text._ZNK17MinimalSubscriber14topic_callbackESt10shared_ptrIN11sensor_msgs3msg6Image_ISaIvEEEE[_ZNK17MinimalSubscriber14topic_callbackESt10shared_ptrIN11sensor_msgs3msg6Image_ISaIvEEEE]+0x37b): undefined reference to `MinimalSubscriber::slope'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/adas_node.dir/build.make:173: adas_node] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:80: CMakeFiles/adas_node.dir/all] Error 2
```

here is my code:

```
class MinimalSubscriber : public rclcpp::Node
{
public:
  
  // --- INFORMATION STORAGE ---
  //save some informations
  static float slope; //<--- declare this value

  MinimalSubscriber()
  : Node("minimal_subscriber")
  {
    slope = 0.0f; //<--- init this value

    subscription_ = this->create_subscription<sensor_msgs::msg::Image>(
      "/carla/hero/semantic_view/image", 10, std::bind(&MinimalSubscriber::topic_callback, this, _1));
  }

private:
  void topic_callback(const sensor_msgs::msg::Image::SharedPtr msg) const
  {
    cv_bridge::CvImagePtr cv_ptr;
    cv_ptr = cv_bridge::toCvCopy(msg, sensor_msgs::image_encodings::BGR8);
    cv::imshow("cv image", cv_ptr->image);

    //Variables
    cv::Mat lane_color_mat(1,1,CV_8UC3, cv::Scalar(61, 232, 154));
    cv::Mat car_color_mat = cv::Mat(1,1,CV_8UC3, cv::Scalar(141, 9, 1));
    cv::Mat image_car, image_lane, frame;
    
    //---set processimages---
    frame = cv_ptr->image.clone();
    image_car = cv_ptr->image.clone();
    image_lane = cv_ptr->image.clone();
    
    //---object isolation---
    int offset_color = 30;
    cv::Mat mask_lane = ipf::ObjectIsolation(image_lane, lane_color_mat, offset_color);
    //cv::imshow("mask_lane", mask_lane); //with one channels 

    //---perspektive transformation
    cv::Size warped_image_size = cv::Size(512, 256);
    
    std::vector<cv::Point2f> roi_src = ipf::DynamicSrc(slope); //<--- use this value
    cv::waitKey(1);
  }

  rclcpp::Subscription<sensor_msgs::msg::Image>::SharedPtr subscription_;
  
};

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
  rclcpp::init(argc, argv);
  rclcpp::spin(std::make_shared<MinimalSubscriber>());
  rclcpp::shutdown();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Linker error, not compiler error. You are not linking the object file (or library) implementing the function you are calling or defining the static variable you are referencing.

Comment: It's simple, you declared `slope` but you did not define it. Many newbies don't realise that you need to define static members. Just add `float MinimalSubscriber::slope = 0.0f;` to your code in a cpp file. And remove the 'init' from the constructor (unless you really want that to happen everytime you create a MinimalSubscriber object).